# On which Android devices is uiautomator available?

Tags: android, ui-automation

I want to use *uiautomator* or *uiautomatorviewer* for Android test automation.
Can I use these tools on any Android device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have a device with Android OS version 4.1 (JELLY_BEAN, API level 16) at minimum. [Documentation reference](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html):

> To use these tools, you must have the following versions of the Android development tools installed:
>     Android SDK Tools, Revision 21 or higher
>     Android SDK Platform, API 16 or higher